# Escaping special characters from html

Tags: c#, html

I am retrieving a string from a webpage via a web browser, however the text on the page has many quotation marks ' and ". I am trying to pull the webpage into a variable, then use the variable as the body of an email. Do I need to swap out every double quote for single quotes OR double up the quotes, or since it is from a web page -> into a string, will it be OK?

Comment: You don't need to quote a string, unless you're literally writing one in your source code. A string is just a bunch of whatever characters it contains. You can assign it to a variable, and use it as the content of an email.

Comment: have you tried all options mentioned by yourself?

Comment: Neverever I have not yet tried creating a function to parse out the quotes or double quotes,  The program is not yet ready to source the aforementioned html so i have not tried that yet, i wanted to understand what sourcing pattern i would use but i appreciate your attemp to "help"

Thank you @CarlSmith !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to escape any "quote" characters because you're not editing source code. It's all in memory.
- If you want rendered html, do nothing, eg If you want `<b>Bold</b>` to produce **Bold**.
- If you want the markup to display in the email, eg `<p>Text</p>`.

  - Replace `<` with `&lt;`
  - Replace `>` with `&gt;`
  - Replace `&` with `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any special handling of quotation marks. If you have a fragment (or all) of an HTML document as a string, you generally *must not* escape the Ascii quotation marks " and ', since they may have special meaning as attribute delimiters, as e.g. in `<div class="foo">` and escaping them would change the meaning. Within element content, in textual HTML format, as opposite to the DOM, they could be escaped as `&quot;` and `&apos;`, but there is no need for that.